# Cannot insert the value NULL into column (MS-SQL) with Store Procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq, stored-procedures

Here is my Table, called Tour_Lists. If my table is empty. Store Procedure work very well. But after insert first row. I continue inserting second row and get error:

**Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Ma_tour', table 'Travel.dbo.Tour_Lists'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. The statement has been terminated.**

What's wrong in my code?

[image]

**Store Procedure**

```
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[ThemTour]    Script Date: 07/05/2013 21:16:14 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ThemTour]
@ten_tour nvarchar(100),
@lich_trinh nvarchar(MAX),
@gia decimal(18,0),
@thoi_gian nvarchar(50),
@khoi_hanh nvarchar(50),
@noi_khoi_hanh nvarchar(100),
@phuong_tien nvarchar(50),
@khach_san nvarchar(30),
@diem_den nvarchar(100),
@anh_dai_dien image,
@trang_thai bit = 1
AS
BEGIN
declare @return nvarchar(100),
@Matourcuoi nvarchar(100),
@sothutu nvarchar(50),
@dodaichuoi int, 
@tangsotour int
select top(1) @Matourcuoi = Ma_tour from Tour_Lists order by Ma_tour desc -- lấy cái MaTour cuối cùng trong bảng
if(@Matourcuoi is not null)
begin
-- Analyzing...
select @dodaichuoi = len(@Matourcuoi) -- cho biết độ dài của chuổi
select @sothutu = substring(@Matourcuoi,3,@dodaichuoi - 2) -- Trả về con số trong chuối, bắt đầu lấy từ ký tự thứ 3 cho đên hêt chuổi (trừ 2 chữ 'NV' ra)
select @tangsotour = convert(int,@tangsotour) + 1 -- cho nó tăng thêm 1 đơn vị, chuẩn bị chèn vô

-- cấu trúc switch-case-default bên SQL là thế này
select @return = case
when len(convert(nvarchar,@tangsotour))=1 then 'Tour000'+convert(nvarchar,@tangsotour) --nếu là số có 1 chữ số
when len(convert(nvarchar,@tangsotour))=2 then 'Tour00'+convert(nvarchar,@tangsotour) -- nếu là 2 chữ số
when len(convert(nvarchar,@tangsotour))=3 then 'Tour0'+convert(nvarchar,@tangsotour) -- nếu là 3 chữ số
when len(convert(nvarchar,@tangsotour))=4 then 'Tour'+convert(nvarchar,@tangsotour) --nếu là 4 chữ số
else 'Tour'+convert(nvarchar,@tangsotour) -- nếu trên 4 chữ số: từ 10,000 trở đi
end -- end of switch-case-default

end -- endif
else select @return='Tour0001' -- nếu chưa có mẩu tin nào trong bảng Tour_Lists
insert into Tour_Lists (Ma_tour,Ten_tour,Lich_trinh,Gia,Thoi_gian,Khoi_hanh,Noi_khoi_hanh,Phuong_tien,Khach_san,Diem_den,Anh_dai_dien,Trang_thai)
VALUES (@return,@ten_tour,@lich_trinh,@gia,@thoi_gian,@khoi_hanh,@noi_khoi_hanh,@phuong_tien,@khach_san,@diem_den,@anh_dai_dien,@trang_thai)
END
```

Comment: As the title say you are asking `why you cannot Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Ma_tour', table 'Travel.dbo.Tour_Lists'' 
The reason for that is that NULL is not allowed

Comment: You might want to reformulate your question. As far as i can tell you would like to know why the parameter @return is NULL

Comment: Check this line of your code: `select @tangsotour = convert(int,@tangsotour) + 1`. Seems like an error is here

Comment: What should I do? @threeFourOneSixOneThree

Comment: @threeFourOneSixOneThree i don't blame you because i don't downvoting your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that once a row has been input, then:

```
    select top(1) @Matourcuoi = Ma_tour from Tour_Lists order by Ma_tour desc
```

gives `@Matourcuoi` a value. This then matches your condition:

```
     if(@Matourcuoi is not null)
```

which goes on to calculates the value of `@return` based on the value of `@tangsotour`. This is null, so the following part of your condition is evaluated (as no other parts are matched):

```
     else 'Tour'+convert(nvarchar,@tangsotour)
```

Adding a varchar to a NULL produces a NULL, so by the time it reaches:

```
    insert into Tour_Lists (Ma_tour,Ten_tour,Lich_trinh,Gia,Thoi_gian,Khoi_hanh,Noi_khoi_hanh,Phuong_tien,Khach_san,Diem_den,Anh_dai_dien,Trang_thai)
    VALUES (@return,@ten_tour,@lich_trinh,@gia,@thoi_gian,@khoi_hanh,@noi_khoi_hanh,@phuong_tien,@khach_san,@diem_den,@anh_dai_dien,@trang_thai)
```

`@return` is still NULL, hence your error.

As I'm unfamiliar with the language used in the sample code, I can't tell what the variables are meant to be, so can't suggest an easy work-around. I'm guessing, though that `@tangsotour` is meant to be the numeric part of `@Matourcui` plus 1 - if so, that step has been missed.

Comment: There's not a specific 'incorrect' line, there's just a step missing that works out a value for `@tangsotour` for you.

Comment: @user2494232 - I think the logic goes wrong on this line: `select @tangsotour = convert(int,@tangsotour) + 1` you've got the same variable on both sides.

Comment: thank you so so much...I edited my code select @tangsotour = convert(int,@sothutu) + 1 and my code work very well :)

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that you never set the identity seed on your table?

Comment: my primary key is varchar. How can i set identity?